# Разрешение перегрузок между функциями без параметров и с параметрами по умолчанию

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int a = 256) // Самое очевидное убрать значение по умолчанию.
{
    std::cout << "default\n";
}
void func() 
{
    std::cout << "no param\n";
}

int main() 
{
    func(); // Ошибка перегрузки.
}
```

Какие еще способы решения данной проблемы есть кроме самой очевидной - убрать значение по умолчанию у функции с аргументом?

Comment: Это единственно провильное решение

Comment: Вы сначала сформулируйте проблему. Зачем вам понадобился такой набор функций? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: готовлюсь к экзамену, в общем даны 2 функции как в примере, и нужно предложить несколько вариантов решения , и вот я уперся в несколько, как из области видимости перегруженной функции повлиять на компилятор так что бы не было ошибки и можно было вызвать функцию func().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно заново объявить функции внутри `main`, в этот раз без значения параметра по умолчанию:

```
int main() 
{
    void func(int);
    void func();

    func(42); // Раз
    func(); // Два
}
```

Comment: Кстати, для решение проблемы достаточно переобъявить только версию без параметра.

Answer (score 2):

Если в момент вызова выполнить явное приведение типа, то оно выберет конкретную функцию из набора перегруженных

```
((void (*)()) func)();
```

То же самое произойдет, если инициализировать указатель требуемого типа и сделать вызов через него

```
void (*p)() = func;
p();
```

Comment: Не могу теперь вызвать первую функцию. `((void(*)(int))func)();` - даёт ошибку.

Comment: @AlexGlebe так надо параметр передать.

Comment: А из самой функции void func(); можно как то повлиять на разрешение?

Comment: @Вася Пупочки: Не ясно, о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 0):

Если перегрузка не удаётся, это значит что ваша новая функция очень индивидуальная. Тогда весь новый код пишите в своём пространстве имён.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c++98 перегруз.cpp
# include <iostream>

void func(int a = 256) // Самое очевидное убрать значение по умолчанию.
{
    std::cout << "Моя жизнь принадлежит Орде" << std::endl; }

namespace VasjaPupochki {    
void func() {    std::cout << "Моя жизнь принадлежит Насте" << std::endl; }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    func();// Ошибка перегрузки.
    VasjaPupochki::func();  }
```

Comment: это отклонение от поставленой задачи